# geth not installed?

Tags: go-ethereum

Followed the documentation here https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

```
$ geth --datadir $DATADIR account new
-bash: geth: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

follow these [instruction](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu) to install it :

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following instructions to install geth:
Step 1: Install go package

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf go1.7.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo mv go /usr/local
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

Step 2: Install go-ethereum

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git
cd go-ethereum
make geth
```

Comment: That installs the Go language itself, not Geth. (Geth is the Ethereum client written in Go.)

Comment: Yaa...I added instructions to install geth in step-2

Comment: Then, to launch geth: `/Users/YourName/go-ethereum/build/bin/geth`